# What to do when you need integers larger than 20 digits on mysql?

Tags: mysql, int, varchar, bigint

Seems like `BIGINT` is the biggest integer available on MySQL, right?

What to do when you need to store a BIGINT(80) for example?

Why in some cases, like somewhere in the Twitter API docs, they recommend us to store these large integers as `varchar`?

Which is the real reason behind the choice of using one type over another?

Comment: BIGINT is limited by definition to 8 bytes.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Big integers aren't actually limited to 20 digits, they're limited to the numbers that can be expressed in 64 bits (for example, the number `99,999,999,999,999,999,999` is not a valid big integer despite it being 20 digits long).

The reason you have this limitation is that native format integers can be manipulated relatively fast by the underlying hardware whereas textual versions of a number (tend to) need to be processed one digit at a time.

If you want a number larger than the largest 64-bit unsigned integer `18,446,744,073,709,551,615` then you will need to store it as a `varchar` (or other textual field) and hope that you don't need to do much mathematical manipulation on it.

Alternatively, you can look into floating point numbers which have a larger range but less precision, or decimal numbers which should be able to give you 65 digits for an integral value, with `decimal(65,0)` as the column type.

Comment: Which is the best for `ORDER` and `WHERE` statements? (With properly settled indexes). For example `SELECT column1 FROM tableA WHERE mybigint > N ORDER BY date LIMIT 100000`. In this case, used to paginate the results.

Comment: @Keyne, decimal values will work okay for that but will probably be slower than raw integral types. The hierarchy of speed will probably be the various raw integrals, decimals, zero-justified varchars and unjustified varchars (fastest to slowest) but you shouldn't trust the advice of some yobbo on the net, even me :-) Measure, don't guess. Then use the fastest that provides the range you need. Specifically, if you need 80 digits, use justified varchars (so that 42 is stored as `0000000000...000000042` for example). ...

Comment: ... For 25 digits, probably decimal(25,0). For 19 digits, bigint. And so on. Your schema isn't locked in forever. If, at some point, you need to move from 19 to 25 digits, then you make the changes at that point from bigint to decimal, otherwise the YAGNI principle probably applies.

Answer (score 8):

You can specify a `numeric(65,0)`, but if you need to get larger, you'll need a varchar.

The reason to select one over another is usage, efficiency and space. Using an int is more efficient than a bigint or, I believe, numeric If you need to do math on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can store that big integers as [an arbitrary binary string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-binary-op.html) if you want maximum storage efficiency.

But I'm not sure if it worth it because you'll have to deal with over 64 bit integers in your application too, which is also [not the thing you want to do](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) without a strong reason.

Better keep things simple and use `varchar`.

Answer (score -8):

BIGINT is limited by definition to 8 digits. The maximum number of digits in DECIMAL type is 64. You must use VARCHAR to store values of larger precision and be aware that there is no direct math of such values.