# How to convert postgres json to integer

Tags: json, postgresql

I can use `to_json(1)` to cast int to json, but how can I convert json to int?  This may be too slow:

```
to_json(1)::text::int
```

Also, is json wrapped from a binary block (bson) or a simple wrapper of text?

Comment: Related: [How to convert Postgres json(b) to float?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24826385/1048572), [to text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27215216/1048572), [to boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33041617/1048572)

Comment: 100::text::jsonb

Answer (score 85):

What works for me (using posgtgresql 5.6) is

```
SELECT (tablename.jsoncolumnname->>'jsonfiledname')::int FROM tablename;
```

like

```
SELECT (users.data->>'failed_login_attempts_count')::int FROM users;
```

Assuming `users` table has a json column named `data` which is something like:

```
{"failed_login_attempts_count":"2","comment":"VIP"}
```

Comment: SELECT (*)::int - That's what I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: `(ta.args ->> 'deposit')::bigint` seemed like it was going to work, but I got `ERROR:  value "1830000000000000000000" is out of range for type bigint`

Comment: Ryan, these answers should help you for sure. the problem is, you just cannot store that big number as integer, because then you lack efficiency in using integers as data types.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142604/what-to-do-when-you-need-integers-larger-than-20-digits-on-mysql

Answer (score 20):

> to_json(1)::text::int maybe too slow

But then, it's the only way.

The second part of your question is unclear.

Answer (score 8):

The PostgreSQL 9.3 JSON support is simply validated json text.

In 9.4 and newer you can use jsonb.

"may be too slow" doesn't make a ton of sense. What makes you think it's too slow? Did you test and benchmark? If it's "too slow" what speed would *not* be too slow, i.e. what do you expect?

Comment: thank you, hope the new version published soon.
since there is a transform between string and number, it will certainly slow than direct integer type, as everybody know. thow it can be accept in real-case useage, we are seeking more fast way.
i put this question under json-to-int question, because i'd suspected json is wrapped from text, this let json-to-int must cast from text,otherwise,it's store structure should be already typed.

Comment: `jsonb` now exists.  Does it support directly extracting integers from json?

Comment: @Craig Ringer - it has problems if value is null:

select ('[null]'::json->0)::text::int  raises invalid input syntax for integer: "null" which makes sense ... 

this works: select ('[null]'::json->>0)::int ... returns null