# In postgresql, how can I return a boolean value instead of string on a jsonb key?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

In the query below, $isComplete and $isValid are returned as a string. However, they are saved as boolean values. How can I get the boolean representation of these fields to be returned?

```
query =
    "SELECT
        data #>> '{id}' AS id,
        data #>> '{name}' AS name,
        data #>> '{curator}' AS curator,
        data #>  '{$isValid}' as \"$isValid\",
        data #>  '{customer}' as customer,
        data #>  '{$createdTS}' as \"$createdTS\",
        data #>  '{$updatedTS}' as \"$updatedTS\",
        data #>  '{$isComplete}' as \"$isComplete\",
        (count(keys))::numeric as \"numProducts\"
    FROM
      appointment_intakes,
      LATERAL jsonb_object_keys(data #> '{products}') keys
    GROUP BY id"
```

Comment: Related: [How to convert Postgres json(b) to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20236421/1048572), [to float?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24826385/1048572), [to text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27215216/1048572)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Simply cast a text to boolean:

```
create table jsonb_test (id int, data jsonb);
insert into jsonb_test values
(1, '{"is_boolean" : true}'),
(2, '{"is_boolean" : false}');

select id, data, (data->>'is_boolean')::boolean as is_boolean
from jsonb_test
where (data->>'is_boolean')::boolean

 id |          data          | is_boolean 
----+------------------------+------------
  1 | {"is_boolean": true}   | t
(1 row)
```

Note that you can also cast other json text values to boolean, examples:

```
insert into jsonb_test values
(3, '{"is_boolean" : "true"}'),
(4, '{"is_boolean" : "false"}'),
(5, '{"is_boolean" : "t"}'),
(6, '{"is_boolean" : "f"}'),
(7, '{"is_boolean" : "on"}'),
(8, '{"is_boolean" : "off"}');

select id, data, (data->>'is_boolean')::boolean as is_boolean
from jsonb_test
where (data->>'is_boolean')::boolean

 id |          data          | is_boolean 
----+------------------------+------------
  1 | {"is_boolean": true}   | t
  3 | {"is_boolean": "true"} | t
  5 | {"is_boolean": "t"}    | t
  7 | {"is_boolean": "on"}   | t
(4 rows)
```

Read  about valid literals for boolean type [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-boolean.html)

---

Update

**Postgres 11** adds casts from JSONB scalars to numeric and boolean data types. This query will work only for *regular* boolean JSONB scalars (i.e. `true` or `false`):

```
select id, data, (data->'is_boolean')::boolean as is_boolean
from jsonb_test
where (data->'is_boolean')::boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres 14 and higher you can use [JSONB Subscripting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-json.html#JSONB-SUBSCRIPTING) to drop the `->` and the `()`:

```
select id, data, data['is_boolean']::boolean as is_boolean
from jsonb_test
where data['is_boolean']::boolean
```