# How to cast postgres JSON column to int without key being present in JSON (simple JSON values)?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, casting

I am working on data in postgresql as in the following `mytable` with the fields `id` (type `int`) and `val` (type `json`):

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "null" |
| 2 | "0" |
| 3 | "2" |

The values in the `json` column `val` are simple JSON values, i.e. just strings with surrounding quotes and have no key.

I have looked at the SO post [How to convert postgres json to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20236421/14015737) and attempted something like the solution presented there

```
SELECT (mytable.val->>'key')::int FROM mytable;
```

but in my case, I do not have a key to address the field and leaving it empty does not work:

```
SELECT (mytable.val->>'')::int as val_int FROM mytable;
```

This returns `NULL` for all rows.

The best I have come up with is the following (casting to `varchar` first, trimming the quotes, filtering out the string "null" and then casting to `int`):

```
SELECT id, nullif(trim('"' from mytable.val::varchar), 'null')::int as val_int FROM mytable;
```

which works, but surely cannot be the best way to do it, right?

[Here is a db<>fiddle with the example table and the statements above.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=75962f63a8babd0b3a60116a5f75d0f7)

Comment: There might be a better way, but I dereference naked json/jsonb scalars with `val->>0`.

Comment: Thank you @Mike, but wouldn't that only work if the values were inside an array? In my tests, `val->>0` returned `NULL` for all my rows.

Comment: That is strange.  Here is what I get in PostgreSQL 10 and 14:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f7dc781ade9125b923e2c99b6c4dc561

Comment: I think the difference is that in your example, the type is `jsonb`, in mine it's `json`. Your approach only seems to work with `jsonb`, whereas the one below for both: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6061e88c05ef86a99402d3a9cd99af93 I'll update my answer to incorporate that info. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the way to do it:

You can access the content via the keypath (see e.g. [this PostgreSQL JSON cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/postgresql-json)):

- Using the `#` operator, you can access the json fields through the keypath. Specifying an empty keypath like this `{}` allows you to get your content without a key.
- Using double angle brackets `>>` in the accessor will return the content without the quotes, so there is no need for the `trim()` function.

Overall, the statement

```
select id
     , nullif(val#>>'{}', 'null')::int as val_int
  from mytable
;
```

will return the contents of the former json column as `int`, respectvely `NULL` (in postgresql >= 9.4):

| id | val_int |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 |

See [updated db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=cf07b6be212956a3b5ad710f43929d1b).

--

Note: As pointed out by [@Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13808319/mike-organek) in his comment above, if the column format is `jsonb`, you can also use `val->>0` to dereference scalars. However, if the format is `json`, the  `->>` operator will yield `null` as result. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6061e88c05ef86a99402d3a9cd99af93).