# Extract Key-Value pairs by conditionally looping over a JSONB array of records in Postgressql

Tags: json, postgresql

I want to write a query that can loop over a list of dictionaries in jsonb object and extract all values that match a specific condition. The table has the following structure.

| UniqueID | Configuration |
| --- | --- |
| uid1 | [{...}, {...}, {...}] |
| uid2 | [{...}, {...}, {...}] |

The list of dictionaries looks like following for each uid.

```
[
  {'insType': 1, 'insMode': 2, 'insOffset': 0.0},
  {'insType': 2, 'insMode': 4, 'insOffset': 1.0},
  {'insType': 2, 'insMode': 5, 'insOffset': 0.0},
  {'insType': 3, 'insMode': 2, 'insOffset': 3.0},
  {'insType': 3, 'insMode': 0, 'insOffset': -1.0},
]
```

I want to find the 'insOffset' for 'insType' == 2 for all my unique ids.

Is there even a way to do it as a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most easily done by using `jsonb_to_recordset` from the [JSON processing functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) in a lateral join

```
SELECT e."uniqueId", c."insOffset"
FROM example e, jsonb_to_recordset(e."Configuration") AS c("insType" int, "insOffset" float)
WHERE c."insType" = 2;
```

Otherwise, you can use `jsonb_array_elements` and access the individual properties, converting them [to floats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24826385/1048572) and [to integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20236421/1048572) respectively:

```
SELECT e."uniqueId", (config ->> 'insOffset')::float AS "insOffset"
FROM example e, jsonb_array_elements(e."Configuration") AS config
WHERE (config ->> 'insType')::int = 2;
```