# How do I get all column values in case of nested json values in column for sql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-json, jsonb-array-elements

Here is a sample of the data that I am working with:

```
id    |  col1    |  col2
1      |  Name1 | {'spec_details': {'spec_values': [{'name':'A','value':2}, {'name': 'B', 'value': 5}, {'name': 'C', 'value': 6}], 'spec_id': 'ASVSDAS'}, 'channel': 'channel1'}
2    | Name2 | {'spec_details': {'spec_values': [{'name':'A','value':9}, {'name': 'B', 'value': 1}, {'name': 'D', 'value': 8}], 'spec_id': 'QWSAASS'}, 'channel': 'channel1'}
```

In the above case, I want to convert the specific `spec_values` present within col2 into seperate columns. So, the output I am looking at is:

```
id   |  col1  |   A  |  B  |  C  |  D | spec_id
1    | Name1  |   2  |  5  |  6  |    | ASVSDAS
2    | Name2  |   9  |  1  |     |  8 | QWSAASS
```

How can I do this? I know I can get the values of `spec_id` by using `->>` So, it becomes `col2->>'spec_id'` for getting spec_id values. In case of `spec_values`, I know I can get specific values at index as `col2->'spec_values'[0]`, and `col2->'spec_values'[1]` etc. Further, can get specific name etc as `col2->'spec_values'[0]->>'name'`

However, am looking to have it as a column instead. Can someone please help?

Comment: What should happen if there's multiple spec values with the same name in the array?

Comment: There can only be one spec value with a given name in the array. However, the number of spec values in the array is not fixed, and vary from 0 to 100 depending upon a given row

Comment: Well, bad data structure then, you should've used an object for that :-) I'll write up an answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did some iterations and was able to get all possible unique values for the column: 
```
SELECT DISTINCT vals->>'name' FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(col2->'spec_details'->'spec_values') AS vals 
FROM table
 ) AS modified_table

```
I was thinking I could add a WHERE clause here by having it on `name` and print its related value in the select query. However, since I used distinct to get all unique `name` values, it is difficult to convert it. Checking using `WITH` if can modify the sql by having cols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would probably be to call `jsonb_path_query_first` multiple times with the respective jsonpath selector. If there might be
duplicates, change it to `jsonb_path_query_array`. The results will have `jsonb` type, you may want to [convert them to `int`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20236421/1048572).

```
SELECT
   id,
   col1,
   jsonb_path_query_first(col2, 'strict $.spec_details.spec_values[*] ?(@.name == "A") .value') AS a,
   jsonb_path_query_first(col2, 'strict $.spec_details.spec_values[*] ?(@.name == "B") .value') AS b,
   jsonb_path_query_first(col2, 'strict $.spec_details.spec_values[*] ?(@.name == "C") .value') AS c,
   jsonb_path_query_first(col2, 'strict $.spec_details.spec_values[*] ?(@.name == "D") .value') AS d,
   jsonb_path_query_first(col2, 'strict $.spec_details.spec_id') AS spec_id
FROM api_listingdata;
```

---

Alternatively, transform the array of name-value pairs into an object, which will make accessing properties by name much easier. `jsonb_object_agg` can be used for that:

```
SELECT
  id,
  col1,
  (
    SELECT jsonb_object_agg(el->>'name', el->'value')
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(col2->'spec_details'->'spec_values') el
  ) AS spec_values,
  col2->'spec_details'->>'spec_id' AS spec_id
FROM api_listingdata;
```

You can also expand such a jsonb object into individual columns using `jsonb_to_record`, including the desired type conversion:

```
SELECT id, col1, "A", "B", "C", "D", spec_id
FROM
  api_listingdata,
  jsonb_to_record(col2->'spec_details') AS spec_details(spec_values jsonb, spec_id text),
  jsonb_to_record(
    SELECT jsonb_object_agg(el->>'name', el->'value')
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(spec_values) el
  ) AS spec_vals("A" int, "B" int, "C" int, "D" int);
```

In any case, you cannot get "all columns in the json" without knowing which columns those are (and ideally, which types they have). Any SQL query must have a static result type that is known before executing the query. If you don't know the column names, either get the JSON (object) value (as shown in the second snippet) and process it in your application logic, or build the SQL query dynamically after determining which columns there are in a previous query.

Comment: I was trying to understand how you are using `jsonb_object_agg` in the above case? And why? Since the value of `spec_values` is already a json itself

Comment: But it's a weird `[{"name":"A","value":2}, {"name":"B", "value":5}, …]` array of tuples not a simple `{"A": 2, "B": 5, …}` object with easily accessible properties.

Comment: Is there a way to loop through column names somehow as a tuple when we are showing the results?

Comment: No, see the last paragraph. You need to do the looping in your application logic.