# Mysql won't store number larger than 9223372036854775808 with bigint

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm hoping that there is a simple fix for this. I have a database column in which I store a number. I knew that the numbers would get pretty big, so I set the field to 'bigint'. However it will not store a number larger than `9223372036854775808`.

Why is this?

Comment: If you set it as unsigned, you can store double the amount

Comment: -1: You should get into the habit of using the reference material.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142604/what-to-do-when-you-need-integers-larger-than-20-digits-on-mysql

Comment: Simple fix: use a string. And given MySQL weird numeric types, it's really more convenient.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html):

> **BIGINT[(M)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]**
>   A large integer. The signed range is -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807. The unsigned range is 0 to 18446744073709551615.

Answer (score 3):

You've hit the bigint maximum size. This is a limitation due to the way the number is stored on the computer. It's the maximum size number you can represent with 8 bytes.

If you need to store a bigger number, consider using another method. You could use varchars but you will need to convert if you're doing math operations on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using a signed BIGINIT:

Range of a signed bigint: -9223372036854775808  - 9223372036854775807
Range of an unsigned bigint: 0- 18446744073709551615

Use ALTER TABLE to modify the column:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY col1 BIGINT UNSIGNED;
```