# difference between `id int(10)` and `id bigint(10)`

Tags: mysql

I am creating a table for that I am using a integer primary key field
I am creating table as

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
 `id`  int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `description` varchar(100),
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 );
```

I read this [Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html). according to this we can store values in int and bigint less than 20 digits.

I would like to know about following

1. What is the difference between `id  int(10)` and `id  bigint(10)`
2. I have used `id  int(100)` is there any problem.
3. what data type should i use for above id(for id value 21 to 100
   digits).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135804/types-in-mysql-bigint20-vs-int20-etcc

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty It gives only my first questions answer

Comment: That should answer all.. int(100) does not do anything.. since it will only accept data for int range..

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Could you tell me how to store more large data in numberic data types between above 21 digits.Is it possible

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142604/what-to-do-when-you-need-integers-larger-than-20-digits-on-mysql it has ur answer !!

Answer (score 1):

There is no meaning of defining digits for int type data as int(10), int(1), int(100) all are same as int and work as same. But **int** and **bigint** are different,bigint will occupy more spaces than int.Details are given below-

```
•tinyint    : 1 byte, -128 to +127 / 0 to 255 (unsigned)
•smallint   : 2 bytes, -32,768 to +32,767 / 0 to 65,535 (unsigned)
•mediumint  : 3 bytes, -8,388,608 to 8,388,607 / 0 to 16,777,215 (unsigned)
•int/integer: 4 bytes, -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647 / 0 to 4,294,967,295 (unsigned)
•bigint     : 8 bytes, -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 / 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (unsigned)
```

Signed   : can contain -ve values (it is default with integer type datatype)

unsigned : can not contain -ve values and have values from 0 to as per integer type

Note: The "unsigned" types are only available in MySQL

Comment: int(1) will store only one digit data. int(5) will store 5 digit data??

Comment: Even you set int(1) still you can store upto 10 digits data as int data type can stored upto 10 digits data.

Comment: If you really want to save space and optimize your data type then you should use tinyint where your requirement is int(1).

Comment: So in my table I have mentioned int(100) this will also store data up to 10 digits

Comment: How can we store more that 20 digits value in numeric data types. or is it limited with only 20 digits

Comment: This isn't quite true. It does have a meaning, when used with ZEROFILL

Comment: in bigint you can store value upto 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

Comment: @Strawberry  I am curious to know data more that bigint above 21 digits