# How to handle large numbers

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to store long integer in table. My table schema looks like
below.

```
CREATE TABLE t7(a long integer);
```

and i am inserting below value.

```
insert into t7(a) values(16732595907054788167);
```

but when i do select i am getting numeric value as below

```
select * from t7;

1.67325959070548e+19
```

And I don't want to use string or blob as data type.
How can I cast numeric to long integer while selecting.

Comment: 16732595907054788167 exceeds the storage capacity of `long integer` (assuming its 64 bits) and approaches the limit for the unsigned equivalent.

Comment: So what do you think which  data type to be used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142604/what-to-do-when-you-need-integers-larger-than-20-digits-on-mysql

Answer (score 2):

SQLite uses signed 64-bit integers, so the largest possible integer value is 9223372036854775807.

And it uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so there's nothing you can do to get larger integers:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    Col1 LONG INTEGER,
    Col2 UNSIGNED LONG INTEGER,
    Col3 EXTREMELY HUGE LONG LONG LONG INTEGER EXTENDED ENTERPRISE EDITION,
    Col4 EH WHATEVER
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (9223372036854775807,9223372036854775807,9223372036854775807,9223372036854775807);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (9223372036854775808,9223372036854775808,9223372036854775808,9223372036854775808);

SELECT * FROM test; 
9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807
9.22337203685478e+18 9.22337203685478e+18 9.22337203685478e+18 9.22337203685478e+18
```

You have to use strings or blobs.

Comment: How if I change data type to unsigned long integer?