# related to the bigint datatype in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, biginteger, sqldatatypes, bigint

declare x bigint;
set x = 180181182149150151152;

Error: Out of range Value for column 'x' at row 1.

So my question is , can i store a big number like the one above inside bigint?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do when you need integers larger than 20 digits on mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142604/what-to-do-when-you-need-integers-larger-than-20-digits-on-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the largest value supported by `BIGINT UNSIGNED`, compared to the number you are using:

```
180181182149150151152 = your number
 18446744073709551615 = 2^64-1, largest value for BIGINT UNSIGNED
```

You can see that your number is on the order of 10x larger than the largest integer value supported by MySQL. Your number would require 68 bits to store, but MySQL only supports [integer data types up to 64-bit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html).

You can store values with larger magnitude in a `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`, but you'll lose precision. In other words, the  You simply can't stuff 68 bits of information into 64 bits of encoding.

```
mysql> create procedure p() begin declare x double; set x = 180181182149150151152; select x; end;;

mysql> call p;;
+-----------------------+
| x                     |
+-----------------------+
| 1.8018118214915015e20 |
+-----------------------+
```

You can use `DECIMAL()` if you give it enough precision:

```
mysql> create procedure p() begin declare x decimal(64,0); set x = 180181182149150151152; select x; end;;

mysql> call p;;
+-----------------------+
| x                     |
+-----------------------+
| 180181182149150151152 |
+-----------------------+
```

Read more: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html